# Python Logging Configuration from both Dict and file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-logging

I looked all morning for a solution.  Nothing seemed to fit.  If anyone has one, I'll be glad to close this. I offer a solution at the end, feel free to let me know if there is anything better.  Not sure why this is not a common issue.

I have a relatively complex testing module that I want to do logging on.  One of the things I want to add is the ability to easily change logging parameters for specific module loggers, etc..  For example, turn on a custom TRACE level for just the USB module, or limit logging from the BLE module(s) to just INFO and above.  It would be nice to change anything, not just level. Some of the modules I use (like Bleak) have logging, but need some configuring from outside the module and so modifying that module is unrealistic.

My test program sets a reasonable set of defaults in the code as a dictionary, but occasionally I would like to, for example turn on TRACE logging for BLE.  Instead of modifying the the dictionary in the original code, I would like to override or update the configuration from a separate configuration file.  I understand why this is not easy from logger.py itself, as it would require the actual logger object factories to re-issue some of the objects (i.e. loggers).

What I came up with is a function to do a deep update of the default configuration dictionary from a configuration update dictionary.  The dictionary update() method is close, but can't handle the nested dictionaries in logging.

For example.  Given the default configuration:

```
debugConfig = {
    'version':1, 
    'loggers':{
...
        'usb_interface':{
            'handlers':['default', 'error', 'file'], 
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate':False}, 
...
}
```

And an update configuration dictionary (read from a file config.py) with:

```
conf.logger = {
    'loggers':{
        'usb_interface':{
            'level':'TRACE',
        },
    },
}
```

I then have the code:

```
def updateConfig(conf, updates):
    for key in updates:
        if key in conf:
            # keys match, update
            if isinstance(updates[key], dict) and isinstance(conf[key], dict):
                updateConfig(conf[key], updates[key])
            else:
                conf[key]=updates[key]

updateConfig(debugConfig, config.logger)
logging.config.dictConfig(debugConfig)
```

The updateConfig function walks through the conf dictionary and updates dictionary trees and overrides matching elements.  I realize there is a possible situation where the conf and update elements would possible have a type mismatch, resulting with, for example an embedded dictionary being overwritten with a simple string, but I deemed that as a feature, not a fault.

This results in the dict:

```
debugConfig = {
    'version':1, 
    'loggers':{
...
        'usb_interface':{
            'handlers':['default', 'error', 'file'], 
            'level': 'TRACE',
            'propagate':False}, 
...
}
```

Hope this helps someone not miss lunch searching around.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed answer is in the question.  Feel free to recommend alternatives.